# Cordova iOS not updating the recent deployed changes

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a Cordova application that will load a url from config.xml.  If there are any updates happens at the server side the changes are not reflecting in iOS. For Android I could able to see the changes once I clear the cache by going to Setting->Apps->Go to my App->Clear Cache but for iOS there is no such thing to clear cache(if I'm right).  I have to uninstall and re-install the iOS Application in order to see the changes.  Are there any other way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timestamp as a parameter to your link to be sure that the browser always reloads the page, like

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
window.location.href = url + '&ts=' + n;
```

getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)